# How to Change Paypal amount value from javascript?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I have a Function which calculates the Grand total how do i change the value of the data-amount to the grandtotal amount using javascript?

```
 <script data-env="sandbox"
                    data-currency="NZD"
                    data-button="buynow" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=test@test.com"
                    async="async"
                    data-amount="0">

            </script>
```

Any help will be great

Comment: Could you show us the Javascript you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean `data-amount`...

```
var scr=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; // assuming that this <script> is first <script> on this page
scr.setAttribute("data-amount", "some new value");
```

Comment: Thanks it worked all I had to do was change [0] to [3] and it worked great.